# undefined symbol error when building react native project with @stripe/stripe-react-native

Tags: xcode, react-native, stripe-payments

Currently trying to integrate and @stripe/stripe-react-native and remove tipsi stripe from a react native project due to multiple issues with xcode 12.5. But integrating the Stripe official library keeps throwing **undefined symbol** error during build time. The suggested fix at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/stripe-react-native does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure to cleared out **all** of the mentioned files/references first *before* creating the new swift file? The sequence does matter, here. You can also closing xcode in between the two steps to ensure all files are saved & reloaded etc.

Review the troubleshooting steps and follow carefully: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/#undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86_64-on-ios

If you continue to encounter problems, you should [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues) with the exact error and reproduction steps (ideally including a sample repository) so the developers can help you to resolve it.

Comment: under library search paths, I see ${inherited} and $(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift,both of which are non recursive. Deleted the second one, create Fix.swift at the root level of the project. Also, my error message does not contain architecture-x86_64. the message reads: Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for (extension in Foundation):__C.NSOperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType

Comment: Did you resolve it @Soham?

Comment: @soham any lead?